# Filtering all objects apart from one and changing their values

Tags: javascript, object, filter, foreach

I have an object which I want to filter only by shops:

```js
const items = {
    "cars": {
        "porshe": {
            "active": true
        }
    },
    "shops": {
        "primark": {
            "active": true
        },
        "zara": {
            "active": true
        },
        "nike": {
            "active": true
        }
    }
}

 const filtered = Object.keys(items)
                .filter((key) => !['cars'].includes(key))
                .reduce((shops, key) => {
                    shops[key] = items[key];
                    return shops[key];
                }, {});
       
console.log(filtered);
```

Now I want to update all active values for "primark", "zara" and "nike" to active:false, and update my items object.

I have no idea how I can achieve that, I will be very grateful for every replies :)

Comment: `!['cars'].includes(key)` - Why this complicated setup instead of a simple string comparison?

Comment: Is that the whole object? If yes, then why `Object.keys().filter()`? `items.shops` would do the same.

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to use array functions on objects for the sake of using array functions on objects. The fastest way to do this is the simplest: `items.shops.primark.active = false; items.shops.zara.active = false; items.shops.nike.active = false;`

Comment: Nope - the object is generic from the backend and here can be much more values. That's why I used !['cars'].includes[key], beacuse it will be more :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you only need simple `for in` loop for object updates which is faster.

```
for (let key in items.shops) {
  items.shops[key].active = false
}
```

Now you can check it with `console.log(items);`